# Can distirbuted processing, OS processes or even threads be used to simulate a non deterministic turing machine adequately on small datasets?

Tags: turing-machines, nondeterminism

For example for the traveling salesman problem which is a proven NP-Complete problem, if we spawn a thread at each node in the graph such that each of those threads will, in turn, spawn as many threads as needed, would this work as a simulation of Non-deterministic Turing machine. Are there any theoretical gaps in this simulation?

For input:

```
1,2  
1,3   
1,4  
2,5
```

- Salesman starts at node 1 spawns 3 threads for 2,3,4
- Each of the nodes 2,3,4 spawn a new thread
- Threads spawned at 3,4 report that there is nothing more to do Nodes 3,4 therefore finish their respective processing and report to Node 1
- Node 2 spawns a thread for 5 which folds as above and Node 2 inturn folds and reports to Node 1 that it can visit 5 in the path 2-> 5
- Node 1 now sees that there are 4 additional nodes in the graph 2,3,4 and 5 and that 2 fails to connect to 3 and 4 thus does not have a path that has complete coverage such that each node can be visited exactly once and the same is true for Node 3 and 4

Will the above be polynomial clock/duration time? (granted it is an extremely oversimplified approximation with possibly large multiplier constants. One may need to build sets at each node for accessible downstream nodes and this set is sent back to their parent)

this question is intended more as a thought experiment than as a question that has an exact yes/no answer. However, still posting it here as I thought there might be obvious reasons to say no because I am missing something fundamental.

Essentially would infinite compute capacity allow for arriving at a solution for NP problems in polynomial clock/duration time from start to finish?

Comment: Could you please define what you mean by "apt" and what you mean by "polynomial time" in this context?

Comment: thanks @D.W. "apt" wasn't needed. dropped the word. and by "polynomial time" I meant some polynomial expression in terms of the number of vertices or edges in the graph for time complexity.

Answer (score 2):

You can of course simulate a non-deterministic TM in this way.

Is it polynomial time?  It depends what you mean by that, but as a first approximation, the answer is no.  The total amount of computation performed -- the total running time, summed across all threads -- will be exponential in general.  For instance, the amount of energy used for this computation will be exponential.  The wall-clock time -- i.e., the time until the last thread finishes -- may theoretically be polynomial, *if* you have a CPU with an unlimited number of cores, so that each thread can run on its own core.  However you will need exponentially many CPU cores, so this is completely unrealistic and only a thought experiment.

In other words, in practice this is completely infeasible unless the size of the problem is exceptionally small -- and if the problem is exceptionally small there are many other ways to do it without needing to spawn multiple threads.

So conceptually this is a fine way to think about non-determinism.  As a practical implementation strategy, normally it will not make sense.